# location.reload(true) crashing browser tab

Tags: javascript, php, timeout

I have a website that uses PHP sessions, and I have implemented the following JS code to check every 60 seconds if a user's sessions is still active:

```
var timeoutInterval = 60000; // 1 minute

function checkTimeout() {
  var timeoutWorker = new Worker("/include/cbpull.js");

  timeoutWorker.postMessage('/cloud/timeout.php');

  timeoutWorker.onmessage = function (result) {
    if (result.data['result'] === false) {
      location.reload(true);
    }
  }
}

function sessionTimeout() {
  checkTimeout();
  setInterval(checkTimeout, timeoutInterval);
}

sessionTimeout();
```

However, this code crashes the tab in Google Chrome when the session is timed out and `location.reload(true)` is called.  What can I do to make the code work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Might the following be what's happening? On a session time-out, you reload the page, which immediately triggers sessionTimeout again, which again finds that the session is (still) expired, which reloads the page...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The first thing that happens when the page is reloaded is I check if the session exists.  If it doesn't, it redirects the user to the login page.